# How to resize JavaFx fxml components with maximizing the window?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I am using JavaFx fxml to develop my GUI project. The problem is they are remaining as same they are defined in side the layout. I am using AnchorPane layout but it gives no result. I had tried GridPane and VBox too. I had watched some youtube videos but they didn't use fxml. Anybody has any idea that how can I make them work?

Comment: Don't use `AnchorPane`. Read [the layout documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) to understand how layout and component resizing works, and make sure you're not setting properties on your layouts and the components inside them that prevent them from resizing correctly.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: I has got nothing to do with type of Pane you are using. I can help but I need some demo code to be sure what the real problem is.

Comment: Try setting the max with and height to a greater value. In `VBox` you will probably need to set `VBox.alwaysGrow`. It's hard to know exactly. We need to see the `FXML`.